# how can i make my flutter application detects other phones using ble?

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using an app that uses Bluetooth low energy to scan and detect devices however it does not detects other phones
is there a specific way on flutter to make it detect other mobile phones

Comment: You can use [flutter_blue](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue) for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can only detect BLE devices that are advertising their services. A mobile phone often does not do that on its own. There are two solutions:

1. Use an already available app on the other device to advertise some service. One of the possible apps I personally use is [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile), another one would be [BLE Peripheral](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.github.webbluetoothcg.bletestperipheral&hl=de&gl=US).
2. This might not be sufficient depending on your project and goal this might not be sufficient. If you need some specific service or characteristic that can't be generated by pre-existing apps you have to develop your own app for advertising. This would be possible with [flutter_ble_peripheral](https://github.com/juliansteenbakker/flutter_ble_peripheral) (limited functionality on iOS)

Comment: Thank you for your reply
i'm actually trying to develop an app that uses BLE for the track of covid-19 but the problem is the app I created can detect smart devices such as smart watches earpods .. etc but not phones
I assume that phones can only be receivers and can not emit BLE signal

Comment: @RedaVexino No, as I said you have to make the phones advertise to detect them. All the other BLE contact tracing apps on the market work like this, they scan for devices around them and also advertise their presence. It is not possible to detect devices that are not advertising using BLE

Comment: You can detect smart watches and such because they are advertising their presence to be found by smartphones. Smartphones don't need (and probably don't want) to be found by other smartphones using BLE on their own